# Where to ask questions related to Real-Time-Systems/Embedded Systems?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I found no tags specific to Real-Time/Embedded system. Neither any question posted. I've few queries specific to real-time scheduling. Which stack-exchange should I use?

Comment: This is a very general question that is unlikely to elicit useful answers. Can you give some examples?

Comment: For example, multiprocessor scheduling algorithms in the context of real time systems.

Comment: Imho, these would be perfectly ontopic for [cs.SE]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend on whether your question is a computer science one; embedded systems touch multiple fields. There are multiple SE sites that potentially fit, for instance these:

- [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) for questions about algorithms, data structures and other principles of data processing.
- [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for programming questions.
- [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for questions about engineering software.
- [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) for questions about electronics, i.e. "the metal".
- [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) for questions specific to robotics.
- [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com) for questions about physical foundations of electronics.

There certainly *are* questions relating to real-time or embedded systems that are ontopic here (I know for a fact that there are computer scientists researching related issues) but not *every* question about such systems is.

As a rule of thumb: if your question is about software in the sense that it applies to many systems, regardless of specific hardware, OS or programming language, it's probably ontopic here; otherwise, it's probably not.

In case of doubt, you can always ask us in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science).